# git push heroku error (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, github

I'm trying to push my rails project onto heroku but I keep receiving this message:

> remote: !       Heroku Git error, please try again shortly.
>
> remote: !       See http://status.heroku.com for current Heroku
>   platform status.
>
> remote: !       If the problem persists, please open a ticket
>
> remote: !       on https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new
>
> remote: !       and provide the Request ID
>   a0ec0d23-526d-4482-a06e-88129776d9af
>
> remote:
>
> To https://git.heroku.com/gracepinteresting.git  ! [remote rejected]
>   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push
>   some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/gracepinteresting.git'

Here's a link to the project at github: https://github.com/gracek93/pinteresting

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure your app is created at heroku try this `heroku apps` to view your app list.

Comment: Can you try it out again ? Are you still receiving the same error ?

Comment: Are you pushing at master like this `git push heroku master`

Comment: Hey Grace, you should try the solution mentioned above. This should work. Double check if heroku is listed when running the command `git remote`. 

Another problem that may not be yours is that heroku is built on top of amazon and amazon is experiencing some issues. This may result in a failure of service at heroku.

We are experiencing several hiccups while developing as amazon is falling behind.

Comment: I tried pushing it again and it worked with no errors, Thanks everyone for your comments!!

Answer (score 0):

heroku has difficulty today. The better now is wait for that Heroku fix their bugs. Check [heroku status here](https://status.heroku.com/)

Comment: yeah i just tried it again now and it seems to be working, thanks for the reply!